# Weird Routing Error in Rails When Manually Adding View

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but when I manually add the view "blah.html.erb" to my project and then visit myproject/dog/blah. It says the following:

Routing Error

No route matches "/dog/blah"

There is an action defined in DogController called "blah" which is the following:

```
def blah 

end
```

NOTE: I add the view using TextMate. I add a new blank file. I think there is some wrong encoding attached to the .html.erb file.

Comment: Can you paste the contents of your routes.rb file (or at least the section that deals with this controller and any global rules). Also, are you using rails 3.x or earlier?

Comment: Ahh it made an entry in the Routes.rb file which I was not aware of. Thanks for pointing it out. If you can list this as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, you need to either have each action listed explicitly in your routes.rb file; or you need a wildcard pattern to match the controller and action.

Answer (score 1):

What's in your routes.rb file?

Better yet, you need to have something like this

match "/dog/blah", :to => "dog#blah", :as => :dog_blah

This tells your rails app that the url /dog/blah maps to the blah action in your DogController, and the :as option will give you a named route that you can use in your view in this case dog_blah_path.